# How to define through any API if my class added to my own managed package

Tags: api, managed-package, soap-api

Is there any way to define, which of my classes are added to any of my own managed packages through any API (Partner, Metadata or Tooling) ?

Comment: So you want to determine this in the packaging org?

Comment: Yes, in the packaging org.